# Is there a name for a monoid with a distinguished absorbing element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid

Let $M = (M,·,1,0)$ be a monoid $(M,·,1)$ together with an distinguished absorbing element $0 ∈ M$, that is such that $∀x ∈ M\colon 0·x = 0 = x·0$.

Does such a structure $M$ have a nice name?

Furthermore, is there a name for such structures $M$, where the units of $M$ are *exactly* the nonzero elements of $M$, i.e. $M^× = M\setminus \{0\}$?

*Example*. Every ring is such a structure when only considering multiplication. Fields are then examples where the units are exactly the nonzero elements.

Comment: On your first question: the absorbing element is unique, right? So I would just call it a "monoid having an absorbing element".

Comment: @drhab It is necessarily unique as $0'=0'\cdot 0=0$

Comment: I have only seen it the way drhab describes. Most authors would probably not deign to give it a special name.

Comment: *Furthermore, is there a name for such structures , where the units of  M are exactly the nonzero elements of M?* that would be a *group* with an adjoined absorbing element, right? (Of course, having adjoined the absorbing element, it's no longer a group.)

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, exactly. A little background for this question: Valuations on fields $F$ are morphisms $F → M$ of such structures (with an additional requirement of some subaddivity of “$+$” and “$∨$”), where $M$ is an ordered group with an adjoint absorbing element at the bottom. Then, $M^×$ would be called the valuation group.

Comment: You might call it a "monoid with zero" for short.

Comment: I think I might just call it “steroid” …

Comment: @drhab I think there can be a notion of "an absorbing element" that is different than "the absorbing element".  If __the absorbing element__ is the element that absorbs all other elements, then __an absorbing element__ can refer to an element that absorbs *some* non-identity element.  For this reason, I favor ZhenLin's suggestion, "monoid with zero".

Comment: @mareoraft Somewhat shrugging I go along with you and Zhen Lin. The proposed terminology indeed excludes ambiguity.

Comment: See my identical question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88014

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A monoid with an distinguished absorbing element is called a *monoid with zero* in the literature.
A monoid with zero in which the units are exactly the nonzero elements is called a *group with zero* [1, p. 5; 2, Def 1.3.1, p. 34; 4] or a *$0$-group* [3].

[1] A. H. Clifford, G. B. Preston, The algebraic theory of semigroups. Vol. I. Mathematical Surveys, No. 7 American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I. 1961 xv+224 pp.

[2] P.M. Higgins, Techniques of semigroup theory. Oxford Science Publications. The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, New York, 1992. x+258 pp. ISBN: 0-19-853577-5

[3] J.M. Howie, Fundamentals of semigroup theory. London Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series, 12. Oxford Science Publications. The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, New York, 1995. x+351 pp. ISBN: 0-19-851194-9

[4] Lallement, Gérard. Semigroups and combinatorial applications. Pure and Applied Mathematics. A Wiley-Interscience Publication. John Wiley & Sons, New York-Chichester-Brisbane, 1979. xi+376 pp. ISBN: 0-471-04379-6

Comment: Another reference is The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups Volume I by Clifford and Preston.

Comment: @martin-brandenburg You are absolutely right. I edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

They are sometimes also called **pointed monoids**. See [arXiv:1909.00297](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00297v1) for instance.