# Name of property that $0 \cdot x = 0$

Tags: group-theory

What's the name of the property that $0 \cdot x = x \cdot 0 = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

I suppose it would be some group theoretic name but I can't recall it and I've searched everywhere, it wouldn't be the identity nor an inverse, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: A look at the comments on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1517237/75923) might help.

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is an absorbing element (for the multiplication) [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element) Synonyms are zero element and annihilating element. (Note that a non-trivial group can never have an absorbing element!)

Comment: I suggest another name: killer element. (not to be confused with Killing form.) ;)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Best not to use that term while waiting in line at the airport though in these days of nervosity :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually at least two properties involved here.

1. Commutative nature of multiplication: $a.b = b.a$
2. Multiplication has an annihilating element (let's call it $A$): $A.x = A$

By using (1.) and (2.), one gets: $A.x = x.A = 0$. The fact that $A$ is $0$ is another sub-theory.